# how to make command button call two methods to insert data into two different table in jsf page

Tags: java, jsf

I have to combine this two commandbutton into single save button which should insert data into one table and image into other.

```
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{user.addUser()}"></h:commandButton>
```

I solved this by , after getting values in managedbean keeping value globally in variable and then inserting data into one table and at end calling another method to insert images into another.This did the job for me.

Comment: You forgot to tell what problem exactly you're facing while doing that. It's namely extremely trivial/obvious to merge the content of 2 methods into one method and replace the 2 command buttons by 1 command button which calls exactly that method.

Answer (score 2):

This really should not be part of JSF or presentation layer at all. Encapsulate your business logic in service class and do all actions there. Don't make your button aware of tables in database at all. Finally, those two actions probably should be in one transaction and that is one more reason not to do this, this is bad design.